# Getting started with AWS Cloud Computing and text processing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I just started to work with cloud computing services since some processes really slowed down my machine. I created an account on AWS (12 months free tier thing) and spend more than a day reading through different tutorials, documentation pages and SO questions. 
I know how to start an EC2 instance, how to connect via ssh and run python scripts but I still think the whole process of starting to work with a cloud computing service is giving newcomers a really hard time.

My case: I'm working with python to process text data (e.g. cosine similarity) in medium-sized  csv-files (up to 1GB). As my first tries ended in really slow processing, I decided to turn to you guys with the following questions:

- More general: Which steps should one take when starting with cloud computing services (to run python scripts)? What is important to know, where to start (like first steps: choosing EC2 what kind of instance)?
- When working with AWS, when do you work with boto3 and when directly via ssh?
- As I'm not very familiar with hardware issues and there are like a thousand possibilities to choose from: What to look for when choosing an EC2 instance (especially when working with text via python)?
- Because I'm trying to process a csv file: What's the best way to work with existing files/store new files? Is it better to store them in a S3 bucket? How to connect?

Sorry if my questions appear a little bit uninformed. I did try to dive into it by myself, but everything is so fuzzy and all information I could find is kind of very general.

Comment: EC2 itself is a huge topic. You should grab the general idea before lump so many things in one question. Anyway, there are untold story from AWS documentation, i.e.. trap like data transfer out cost,  choosing  lambda over EC2 or use of spot instance, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

congrats on getting through the first few tutorials and successfully getting off the ground with your own EC2 instance! While the cloud has many benefits, it still has a bit of overhead when getting started that can be tough for newcomers, but feedback just like this helps us improve the developer experience.

*1. Which steps should one take when starting with cloud computing (to run python scripts?)*

It seems like you've already gotten your feet wet by SSHing into an EC2 instance (which is going to most closely mimic a terminal on your system), but I figured I'd help supply you with a few other options you have for running python scripts in the cloud based on your use case.

- [AWS Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/): a cloud IDE, which can more easily access other services and resources on AWS cloud. If vim/emacs aren't your cup of tea, being able to code directly from this browser-based IDE might make a big difference, rather than coding locally and constantly pushing code up to your EC2 instance.
- [Amazon SageMaker hosted notebooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs-setup-working-env.html): These are managed Jupyter/JupyterLab notebooks that enable you to run Python (or a kernel of your choice) in cells, which are modular chunks of code. They're extremely popular amongst folks that write code for data processing (data scientists, ML/AI researchers, etc), and you can have one started and running in less than five minutes, and you won't need to worry about SSH.

*2. What is important to know, where to start (like first steps: choosing EC2 what kind of instance)?*

The ideal instance type will be the one at the favorable intersection of price and performance for your given workload and budget. [There are a large number of different EC2 instance classes](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/), each optimized for different workloads.

For choosing an instance to speed up your specific workload, I would need to know a bit more about the code itself to figure out what your computational bottleneck is -- would increasing RAM size allow for larger batches thus speeding up the computation, or is it possibly an inefficient algorithm with exploding complexity that only requires more compute? Is the process parallelizable, and thus would it benefit from leveraging GPUs?

*3. When working with AWS, when do you work with boto3 and when directly via ssh?*

`boto3` is the AWS Python SDK that enables programmatic access (creating, reading, updating, or deleting) to other AWS resources at runtime from within your scripts. This enables any functionality you could perform from the console to be done during workload processing. A common example may be pulling a dataset from S3, or pushing a transformation job off to EMR (Elastic Map Reduce). Alternatively, you can use the `awscli` command line utility to perform these same actions outside of a runtime, directly from bash. SSH is used for directly accessing the server, either to modify the contents, to run commands, or debug.

*4. What to look for when choosing an EC2 instance (especially when working with text via python)?*

The biggest precursor question here is this: what is the computational profile of your workload? As mentioned in A2, while choosing an instance that is more powerful across all major properties (RAM, CPU cores/speed, GPU, networking, etc) will almost guarantee speeding up your process, you are likely going to be overpaying/underutilizing as only a subset of those resources will be the true bottleneck for your system. Finding which type of hardware is currently at maximum capacity in your current workload will help you figure out what type of instance to provision.

Off the cuff, I'd recommend a `C-class` (compute optimized) instance or `P-class` (GPU/parallel compute optimized) instance, depending on whether your process is parallelizable with a GPU.

*5. Because I'm trying to process a csv file: What's the best way to work with existing files/store new files? Is it better to store them in a S3 bucket? How to connect?*

Storing in S3 is likely to be ideal considering it will enable other services to more easily access the file(s) (whether that's other AWS services in the cloud, or you trying to pull the file from outside of AWS). Also, it enables you to tear down the server once your computations are done, and the file will persist on S3 permanently.

Hope these answers help - your questions are totally natural, and the right ones to be asking! Welcome to AWS, and happy hacking!

Comment: Thanks for putting this together - really helps understanding some fundamentals. Regarding my specific case: I'm calculating cosine similarity scores for text in approx 130k rows. Every row is compared to ~100 other rows and for now I don't see a way to parallelize this task.

Answer (score 1):

*1, 3. Which steps should one take when starting with cloud computing services (to run python scripts)? What is important to know, where to start (like first steps: choosing EC2 what kind of instance)?*

- Infrequent processing : t2/t3 or use Lambda. Infrequent batch processing : Spot.
- Understand the credit based burst processing limitation of t2/t3.
- Always study the instance actual cost consequences
- Know you data transfer requirement. Don't simply host website inside EC2 without knowing the data transfer cost. Many people learn the lesson the hard way(after they saw the hefty data transfer out to internet bill).

*2. When working with AWS, when do you work with boto3 and when directly via ssh?*

- For beginner, use ssh and AWSCLI to get familiar with AWS
- Try limit boto3 usage for AWS services access, don't use it to build deployment automation.
- In long term, you must think of learning deployment tools such as Terraform/cloudformation/etc. It is tempting to use boto3 to construct your own deployment.

*4. Because I'm trying to process a csv file: What's the best way to work with existing files/store new files? Is it better to store them in a S3 bucket? How to connect?*

- Just google around the "step by step example" regarding setup EC2 to enable connection to to s3
- Don't simply signed and shared S3 file unless you know what you are doing
- You can make use of [AWS free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free) to play around with the services and security setting. As long as you keep the data transfer out from AWS minimal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I found with starting to learn the Cloud is there are so many things available its easy to get lost.  I would suggest you consider simplifying your approach to the cloud.  You might want to consider 3 simple steps.

1) Learn about S3 and setting up an S3 bucket.  This is pretty easy.

2) Use [boto3](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) and connect from your own PC to the S3 bucket and read and write files to the S3 bucket in python.

3) Now try to take your python code and run it in a lambda function using the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/)  You may find lamdba functions fit your use case.  If not add another step to configure EC2 and run your same function there.  I'm not strong as a sys admin so I think lambda first.

Good luck and congratulations on your start.